# OSpline implementation with correct parabolas

Tags: math, opengl, geometry, coordinate-systems

So my homework is to create an opengl program that can transform points to sphere geometry and correctly connect them.
The first task is to create the shape of africa using the given controll points and an implementation of ospline.
I haven't found any reference to ospline so here it is:

OSpline is an interpolation between 2 parabolas, you give it 4 points, it creates 2 parabolas from 3-3 points and linearly interpolates the middle 2:

[image]

I created a desmos page for my implementation so you can see how i calculate it:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2ftend6wbp

Now this works well for most parts but obviously i have an issue with it:

[image]

Left is the result. Right is how it should look.
The coordinates are not exactly right but it should give a rough shape of the one on the right.

Now the problem is, that when you create a parabola on the top-right 3 points, it creates a normal U shaped parabola as one would expect, since y cannot have 2 values in this implementation.

The solution is that those 3 points can also define a parabola shaped like this: ⊃
Interpolating that parabola would give me the correct result.

But since y has 2 values in a parabola like that, i would have to calculate it entirely differently.
And i would also have to check somehow that i need that exact parabola sideways.

I would like to know if there is a way to check for this, or can i use another coordinate system that can solve this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this part of the task today, so 'll try to guide you, but I won't tell my entire solution.

The formula for a pont on a parabola is S(t) = A(t-t_i)^2 + B(t-t_i) + C. Where you seem to interpret A, B, and C as numbers, but they should be vectors! (this way it gives an implicit equation, so "y can get 2 values") Also your mathematical solution seem way too complicated. I got a much simpler equation for the points.

Suppose that the three point that you want to include in the parabola, are indexed as -1, 0 and 1.

To get A, B, and C you should consider the cases where t = 0, (in this case the equation should give the middle one, of the three points) when t = -1, (it gives the first point), and when t = 1 (it gives the last point). Out of these three equations you can express each variable.

It kind of obvious, but C should be equal to the middle point. I'll leave the rest to you. Good luck.